# how to convert columns to numeric while keep those failed intact in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I read my text file into pandas dataframe. All columns are object datatype. What I need to do is convert all those columns that appears 'numeric' to numeric columns. 
If there are ust a few columns, it's very easy. But my real dataframe has over two hundred columns. I wonder if there is anyway to convert those columns to numeric while keep those which are unable to be converted intact. 
For example, I have the dataframe below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1', '2', 'NA', '4'],
              'b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
              'c': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
              'd': ['11', '22', '33', '44']})
df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']] = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].astype(int)
```

I got error. How can I convert column a and d to numeric while keep b and c as object? Again, my real dataframe has many columns, this is just an example to illustrate my point. I don't want to do allthe hardcoding to convert dtype for every columns.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Op1. I usually using `to_numeric` then `fillna` (The reason : I usually have some mixed dtype within one column )

```
df=df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(df)
df.dtypes
Out[605]: 
a     int64
b    object
c    object
d     int64
dtype: object
```

Op2. Or you can using `to_numeric`+`ignore`

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore').dtypes
Out[608]: 
a     int64
b    object
c    object
d     int64
dtype: object
```

Update

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(df).applymap(type)
Out[652]: 
                 a              b              c              d
0  <class 'float'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'float'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
2    <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
3  <class 'float'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
```

If you want , you can add `df = df.replace('NA',np.nan)`  before running the 1st

Update 2

```
s=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').dropna(axis=1,thresh=1)

pd.concat([s,df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(s.columns)]],1).dtypes
Out[668]: 
a    float64
d      int64
b     object
c     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much. This is what I need.  Especially option one. That is very useful!

Comment: @zesla the 1st one when there is mix dtype in that column, they still convert those 'numbers'  :-) , fillna will cover the str:-)

Comment: I found  there is one problem in your first option.  I just edited the question and introduced a string 'NA' in column a. After using your first method (pd.to_numeric with coerce then fillna, the dtype of column a is still object. How can I make the first column int? Thank you very much.

Comment: @zesla 'NA' is not np.nan, when you are using 1st option , the whole column still will be mixed type, but when you doing df.applymap(type), you will see the number already become int , 'NA' will still be the object

Comment: Thank you. I know 'NA' is not np.nan. I was just trying to introduce a string into that column. The column dtype is still object, although it's 'mixed' type.  Is there any efficient way to convert those 'mix' column to numeric and convert those str element to np.nan?  I need to apply some numeric function on those columns.   It's easy to do it with a couple of columns if I know the column names. The problem is I have so many columns in my messy dataset. Sorry to have so many follow-up questions. Thank you so much for your help! @Wen

Comment: @zesla update again :-)  You do not need to feel sorry about it , It is my pleasure to share my experience . :-) \

Comment: @ this is really smart way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @zesla one more thing, cause np.nan is define as float type, so that column can not be int when there is np.nan

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['a','d']]=df[['a','d']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int))
```

Comment: you don't need the `apply` here. in the more general case, that'll just slow things down.